# PHP to create table rows

Tags: php, html-table

Struggling a bit (I'm learning PHP) to create table rows when a new user is added. I have tried re-arranging my code but still not working.

So here is my code:

```
<?php
$args1 = array(
 'role' => 'committee',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);
 $committee = get_users($args1);
foreach ($committee as $user) {



echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Job Title</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Members Name</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Email Address</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">telephone Number</th>            
  </tr>';

echo '  
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->job_title .'</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">' . $user->display_name .'</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->user_email . '</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->tel_number . '</td>
  </tr>
</table>';

 }
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

The problem I am facing is that when a new user is added it creates the table headers also but I just require the second row?

Comment: Move the table headers to outside (before) the loop?

Comment: I tried that but when a new user is added the old user dosnt sit inside the td's

Answer (score 0):

Just move your first echo out of the foreach:

```
<?php
$args1 = array(
 'role' => 'committee',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);
$committee = get_users($args1);

echo '
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">Job Title</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">Members Name</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">Email Address</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">telephone Number</th>            
      </tr>';

foreach ($committee as $user) {
    echo '  
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->job_title .'</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">' . $user->display_name .'</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->user_email . '</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->tel_number . '</td>
      </tr>';
}
echo '</table></ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

So echo `<table>` before loop.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach () {
    echo "<tr>...</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

move the `echo '<table....` from inside to outside `foreach`

```
<?php
$args1 = array(
 'role' => 'committee',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);

$committee = get_users($args1);

echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Job Title</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Members Name</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Email Address</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">telephone Number</th>            
  </tr>';

foreach ($committee as $user) {

echo '  
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->job_title .'</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">' . $user->display_name .'</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->user_email . '</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->tel_number . '</td>
  </tr>
</table>';

 }
echo '</ul>';
?>
```